# On Debin Stretch, LXDE doesn't scale-down some application icons

Tags: debian, icons, user-interface, lxde, stretch

I use IceWeasel on Debian Stretch, with LXDE.

While most application icons display just fine (including IceDove), the IceWeasel icon exhibits a problem. Very often (but not always!) the large icon is not scaled to fit the taskbar, and I only see its top-left corner. I can't quite make out what the exact conditions for this are. How do I fix this? And is it a bug, a misconfiguration or an issue with the icon somehow?

Here's a screenshot of the Alt-Tab menu:

[image: Alt-Tab menu]

and here's the icon of which I'm only getting the corner:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with how LXDE reads the IceWeasel icons specifically:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=803165

There's a workaround describe on that bug page - regenerating the PNG icons from an SVG original, using inkscape in command-line mode.

```
for n in 16 32 48; do inkscape -z -e /usr/share/iceweasel/browser/chrome/icons/default/default$n.png -w $n -h $n /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg; done
for n in 16 32 48 64 128; do inkscape -z -e /usr/share/icons/hicolor/${n}x${n}/apps/iceweasel.png -w $n -h $n /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/iceweasel.svg; done
```